# Access Hidden Inputs in Django forms class

Tags: django, forms, validation

Need help accessing Hidden inputs in a Form `clean_data` or `clean function`. Unable to find solution here and **Django docs** after about 1 hr of searching.

```
class AccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Account
    #action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput()) <--- also tried this

    exclude = [
        "a_account_number"
    ]

# Validate that there isn't already an account that exists with a similar company name during account creation
def clean_a_company_name(self):
    logging.debug("Value of action %s") % self.data.__getitem__('action')

    if Account.objects.filter( a_company_name = self.cleaned_data['a_company_name']).exists() and % self.data.__getitem__('action')== 'create':
        logging.debug("In account views - form validation - clean_a_company - company already exists raising exception *****************")
        raise forms.ValidationError(u"An organization with this name and owner already exists. Change the Organization name or edit Organization Account information instead of creating a new Organization Account")
    return self.cleaned_data["a_company_name"]
```

Above gives a unicode error.  I also tried:

```
%self.fields['action']
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to access `action` field in method for cleaning `a_company_name`?
You don't have access to other field in field's clean method. You should use form's `clean` method.

From django docs:

> The Form subclass’s clean() method.
>   This method can perform any validation
>   that requires access to multiple
>   fields from the form at once. This is
>   where you might put in things to check
>   that if field A is supplied, field B
>   must contain a valid email address and
>   the like.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Comment: Here is my template:  {% extends "site_base.html" %}
{% block title %}Editing Organization Account Information{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% ifequal account.owner_id request.user.id %}
    <form id="edit-account" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <table>
         {{account_form.as_table}}
         </table>
            <input id="action" type="hidden" name="action" value="edit" />
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Update" %}"/>
    </form>
    {% else %}
    <p>{% trans "You are not the owner of this account." %}</p>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endblock %}

Comment: Ok, so `action` field is not part of your model form. In this case you can achieve the desired functionality in a number of ways: 1) check `request.POST.get('action')` after form validation 2) Write custom Form (not ModelForm)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I need to access the hidden input in the validation code to see if this action is an edit in which case it is ok to have an account already exist.  Request.Post is not available in Forms clean function. Didn't want to write a custom form but it looks like I may have to.